# Use string to search folder and import file in R

Tags: r, regex, find, glob

I am trying to search a folder and import multi-layer rasters based on character values (s).

How do I import the files that match the string and keep their names?

```
#use shp and y to find orthos
ortho <- crop(MrSID_shp, y)
s <- ortho[[2]] 
s
#"3_5" "2_5"

#use s values to search folder with corresponding name
file.is <- Sys.glob("*.tif")
print(file.is) # "0_0.tif" "2_5.tif" "3_5.tif"

for (i in seq_along(file.is)){
file.is[[i]] <- stack(file = file.is[i],
                      pattern = s,)
}
#this results in empty values
```

I have tried grep, find and lapply but have been unsuccessful. I have been able to import "3_5.tif" using the pattern of 's' but I need to import all the files that match, not just one.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for your example (I manually created `file.is` where you would want to use `Sys.glob("*.tif")`):

```r
s <- c("2_5", "3_5")
file.is <- c("0_0.tif", "2_5.tif", "3_5.tif")

unique(sapply(s, grep, file.is, value = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you Mike, that worked! Would you be able to advise on the best way to import these files that have different extents? Not sure if this warrants a new Question.```toimport <- unique(sapply(s, grep, file.is, value = TRUE)) | stack(toimport)``` does not work. Thank you!

Comment: Glad that it worked! When you say "extent" do you mean geographic extent (i.e., getting `s` for the different datasets)? (P.S. if the answer worked, would you mind accepting the answer?)

Comment: Accepted - thank you! Not s. When I go to read in ```stack(toimport) #Error in compareRaster(rasters) : different extent```. I am not sure what to do here, I have read up on mask, disaggregate and resample to alter the extents of the files listed in `toimport` but I am not sure which is best to use. I was hoping I would not need to alter the extents. Once these tif's are imported I will be cropping them with a shapefile. Is there a route you would advise? Thank you

Comment: I tried `resample(toimport) # Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘resample’ for signature ‘"character", "missing"’`. I assume that because `toimport` is a character vector and I cannot use this to select the files to import. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Jade, that makes sense. I think that it would be worth posting a different question. It has helped me, though, to think in terms of functions. If you can write a function that does what you want for a single entity, then you can always loop through them with the `apply` family.

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: I am using raster library

Comment: Given that the question is specific to that library, I would ask a different question. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Mike, I appreciate your help and guidance!